# Não consigo converter segundos em minutos

Tags: mysql

Estou fazendo a seguinte query:

```
    SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(sum(Total_Segundos_Consumidos)/count(distinct IDTRANSACTIONS)) AS `Tempo Médio` 
    FROM
    (SELECT IDTRANSACTIONS, 
    SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TimeDiff(TIME_FORMAT(DATEFIM,'%H:%i'), 
                             TIME_FORMAT(DATEINI,'%H:%i')))) AS Total_Segundos_Consumidos
    FROM TEMPO
    GROUP BY IDTRANSACTIONS) AS Q
```

E não está funcionando.

O seguinte erro aparece:

> Bad format for Time '-05:46:27.2727' in column 1

Isso ocorre, porque ao rodar apenas o comando de dentro, traz números negativos:

> -80340, -86040

Exemplos em http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8cedc9/11

Meu objetivo é pegar o tempo de atendimento e extrair uma média do tempo. No link acima, coloquei os tempos de um dos usuários para servir de exemplo.

Comment: é possível ter esse tempo negativo? não está errado o cálculo _interno_ que você está fazendo?

Comment: Use a função ABS (Absoluto) que não ocorrerá: SUM(abs(TIME_TO_SEC(...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema com a seguinte query:

```
    SELECT TIME_FORMAT((TIMESTAMP(SEC_TO_TIME(round(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(second,DATEFIM,DATEINI))/count(*),0)))),'%H:%i:%s') as `Tempo Médio de Emissão`
    FROM
    (SELECT IDTRANSACTIONS,
    DATEFIM, DATEINI
    FROM TEMPO
    GROUP BY IDTRANSACTIONS) AS Q
```

Agradeço aos que tentaram ajudar. :)

Obs.: No SQLFiddle, o resultado está ficando errado, mas no Dbeaver (onde eu estou executando), está correto.

Answer (score 4):

#### Como fazer

Uma forma mais simples seria usando a função `SEC_TO_TIME` com `TIMESTAMPDIFF`:

```
SELECT IDTRANSACTIONS, 
       SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(second, DATEINI, DATEFIM)) AS 'Tempo Médio de Emissão'
FROM TEMPO
GROUP BY IDTRANSACTIONS, DATEINI, DATEFIM;
```

---

#### Explicando

A função `TIMESTAMPDIFF`, diferente da `TIMEDIFF`, você consegue parametrizar o retorno para segundos (second): `TIMESTAMPDIFF(second, DATEINI, DATEFIM)`.

Em seguida, a função `SEC_TO_TIME` irá converter os segundos para o formato "*HH:MM:SS*".

---

#### Veja funcionando no [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7tKXRcbut35KB5MNJPHn3R/0)

---

#### Referências

[Date and Time Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Answer (score 2):

Para referência futura:

Uma consulta que parece mais simples, explora um pouco mais os recursos de banco e diminui o *overhead* para resolver o problema exposto seria:

```
SELECT
  TIME_FORMAT( SEC_TO_TIME( AVG( TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,  
                                               DATEINI,
                                               DATEFIM))), 
               '%H:%i') AS Total_Segundos_Consumidos
FROM TEMPO;
```

Veja funcionando no [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8cedc9/44).

Referência: [Resposta do rbz](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/330119/78713).

Answer (score 1):

Se você extrair os minutos da diferença de hora, se você quer os minutos como resultado final esse deve servir:

```
EXTRACT(minute from TIMEDIFF(DATEFIM, DATEINI))
```